# How to get images instead of radio boxes for Contact Form 7 in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, forms, contacts

I tried the steps as discussed in this thread: [Use image as radio button on Contact Form 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740637/use-image-as-radio-button-on-contact-form-7/54081069#54081069)

However nothing happens. I just the the text show up on the page.

Any advice?

Comment: add some screenshot of your configuration or of the result form code

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. How do i attach a screenshot here?

Comment: I did 4 things: 1 - added that code to functions.php, 2 - added into style.css, 3 - entered info into contact form, made a test page wit that contact form. here is what is on the contact form [imageradio radio-312 "Value1!http://wpquestions.com/uploads/blondishnet_phpAypIEK.jpg" "Value2!http://wpquestions.com/uploads/blondishnet_phpAypIEK.jpg"]


[radio radio-300 "1" "2"]
[radio]