# Field no longer required when use image as radio button on contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, contact-form-7

I use this tutorial [Use image as radio button on Contact Form 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45740637/use-image-as-radio-button-on-contact-form-7) to put images instead of radiobuttons and it works well but now the field is no longer required. I don't want that users are able to submit the form without select option from the image/radio button.
Any ideas on how to solve this ? Theme used is Storefront with Boutique child theme. May be a conflict with a hook ? I don't find
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your code but if it is a copy from the link you provided, it would look like this:

```
$datalist .= sprintf(
 '<label><input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" class="hideradio" /><img src="%s"></label>', $tag->name, $radiovalue, $imagepath 
);
```

try adding "required" to the input like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="%s" value="%s" class="hideradio" required="required" /><img src="%s">
```

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Thanks, yes it is a copy from the link I provided. I try the attribute required="required" and also just required - but it doesn't seem to work.